Neovim colorschema stops working if nvim runs within screen 4.9 and Ubuntu 24.04
When I run nvim in gnome-terminal its color schema works as expected:

But after launching the screen, the color schema is broken (it's not disabled/gone, it just colors everything incorrectly):

Some more examples of python script:


If I actually change :colorscheme elflord, it will look like this:


NOTE: notice that elflord breaks colorscheme completely in case of nvim in screen.
Other similar questions are on StackOverflow and the usual suspects are $TERM, $XTERM, etc. In this case, I have a suspicion it's more related to Ubuntu 24.04. Initially, it was working till about the end of August 2024 when after a regular sudo apt upgrade it stopped coloring properly. I am not 100% certain it was caused by an upgrade but on my other PC I installed Ubuntu 24.04 in September 2024 and it never worked there.
Other bits and pieces of the information.
:checkhealth of nvim without screen:
 77 nvim: require("nvim.health").check()
 78 
 79 Configuration
 80 - OK no issues found
 81 
 82 Runtime
 83 - OK $VIMRUNTIME: /squashfs-root/usr/share/nvim/runtime
 84 
 85 Performance
 86 - OK Build type: Release
 87 
 88 Remote Plugins
 89 - OK Up to date
 90 
 91 terminal
 92 - key_backspace (kbs) terminfo entry: key_backspace=\177
 93 - key_dc (kdch1) terminfo entry: key_dc=\E[3~
 94 - $VTE_VERSION="7600"
 95 - $COLORTERM="truecolor"
 96 
 97 External Tools
 98 - WARNING ripgrep not available

:checkhealth of nvim with screen:
 77 nvim: require("nvim.health").check()                                                                                        
 78                                                                                                                             
 79 Configuration                                                                                                               
 80 - OK no issues found                                                                                                        
 81                                                                                                                             
 82 Runtime                                                                                                                     
 83 - OK $VIMRUNTIME: /squashfs-root/usr/share/nvim/runtime                                                                     
 84                                                                                                                             
 85 Performance                                                                                                                 
 86 - OK Build type: Release                                                                                                    
 87                                                                                                                             
 88 Remote Plugins                                                                                                              
 89 - OK Up to date                                                                                                             
 90                                                                                                                             
 91 terminal                                                                                                                    
 92 - key_backspace (kbs) terminfo entry: key_backspace=\177                                                                    
 93 - key_dc (kdch1) terminfo entry: key_dc=\E[3~                                                                               
 94 - $VTE_VERSION="7600"                                                                                                       
 95 - $COLORTERM="truecolor"                                                                                                    
 96                                                                                                                             
 97 External Tools                                                                                                              
 98 - WARNING ripgrep not available    

echo $TERM
xterm-256color for gnome-terminal
screen.xterm-256color for screen in gnome-terminal
cat ~/.screenrc
# /etc/screenrc

encoding UTF-8

startup_message off
vbell off

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# STARTUP SCREENS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string '%{= kG}[ %{G}%H %{g}][%= %{=kw}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}][%{B}%Y-%m-%d %{W}%c %{g}]'

In addition I tried:

downgrading nvim to 0.9.x (and using regular sudo apt install neovim)
exporting hardcoded $TERM in .bashrc and .screenrc
a lot of googling if someone reported something similar for screen, neovim, ubuntu 24.04
changing termcapinfo into many different things in .screenrc

